# Non-required store-view attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, catalog

It seems there is a problem in writing attribute's values during import for default store view (id 0) similar to this one http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/177994/ - see my reply as well

Most important that it also affects `special_price` attribute which is also not required. While special prices are displayed in product listing and view pages they are not applied after add to cart. Problem can be resolved manually resaving product from backend or by setting it as required before import

Anyone faced the problem? Am I missing something or this is indeed a bug?